# How to search for a substring in all fields of all documents in a collection in DocumentDB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, nosql

I need to find all documents that contain a substring in any field,
 
**i.e. documents:**

```
{
    a:"asd",
    b:100,
    c:
      {
          z:9
      }
},
{
    v:"asdfg",
    p:"a100"
}
```

So when I search for **`"asd"`** or for **`"10"`**, I need to get both documents.

I don't know what fields can be in these documents, so I cannot just search by each of them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Searching across all fields across all documents would mean having to scan through every DocumentDB, since this type of query doesn't take advantage of any indices.

I would suggest taking a look at a full text search product (e.g. [Azure Search](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/search/)) rather than a database (e.g. [DocumentDB](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/documentdb/)) for this kind of scenario.

Can you elaborate on your use-case and what you're trying to accomplish? Feel free to ping me (andrl {at} microsoft) - I'd be more than happy to provide guidance.

Comment: This is a requirement for this app to search in all fields of all documents. I wanted to dump all field values to one field and search for a substring in that field, but DocumentDB doesn't support a search by a substring yet. And Azure Search seems to be an overkill, I don't need a free text search with synonyms etc. Also there won't be a heavy load here, just few dozens of requests per day.

Comment: Your right - DocDB doesn't have support substring querying just _yet_. A potential workaround is to leverage intra-document JOINs to search whether a given token exists in a JSON Array (similar to array.contains()). You can see a [example demonstrated here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27390189/where-clause-on-an-array-in-azure-documentdb/27390644). How many fields and documents would you be querying across?

Comment: This is a bit late, but it also doesn't look like Azure Search supports nested json at the moment like in OPs case `{
c:{
z:9
}
}`


I'm bringing this up because I also need to be able to search on substrings of fields.

Comment: Correct - you would need to write some code to flatten your JSON for Azure Search (e.g. `{foo:{bar:false}}` => `{"foo.bar":false}`). If by chance you are using both Azure Search and DocumentDB - Azure recently built a Search indexer for DocumentDB to integrate the two products together... In which case, you can use leverage DocumentDB query projections, when defining the `data source`, to flatten JSON documents to be indexed by Azure Search.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your use case, Azure Search (with suggestions enabled) seems to be more appropriate. Search suggestions is what allows azure search to deliver result hits based on substrings.