# Should I have posts and comments as different collections?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am reading the following documentation [about Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/social-media-apps)

In this documentation they have the following post

```
{
    "id":"ew12-res2-234e-544f",
    "title":"post title",
    "date":"2016-01-01",
    "body":"this is an awesome post stored on NoSQL",
    "createdBy":User,
    "images":["http://myfirstimage.png","http://mysecondimage.png"],
    "videos":[
        {"url":"http://myfirstvideo.mp4", "title":"The first video"},
        {"url":"http://mysecondvideo.mp4", "title":"The second video"}
    ],
    "audios":[
        {"url":"http://myfirstaudio.mp3", "title":"The first audio"},
        {"url":"http://mysecondaudio.mp3", "title":"The second audio"}
    ]
}
```

And they say that the following comments can be just another post with a parent property

```
{
    "id":"1234-asd3-54ts-199a",
    "title":"Awesome post!",
    "date":"2016-01-02",
    "createdBy":User2,
    "parent":"ew12-res2-234e-544f"
}

{
    "id":"asd2-fee4-23gc-jh67",
    "title":"Ditto!",
    "date":"2016-01-03",
    "createdBy":User3,
    "parent":"ew12-res2-234e-544f"
}
```

Does that mean I store both document types in the same collection or I should have two collections, one for each document type?

I know I can store them in the same collection my question is about what is the best way of doing it since the documentation is not clear.

Comment: Please take a look at this presentation on Modeling Data for NoSQL ... I believe your question is discussed here   https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/P468

Answer (score 0):

As usual with these kinds of questions: It depends.

Putting multiple document types into a single collection is definitely not a "bad practice", although you might want to look into adding a "type" parameter or similar to your document so you can filter them more easily.

You pay a flat fee per collection (depending on the RU/s). So if you provision many collections, you might end up paying too much. Less collections are probably better in most cases if your data shares a common domain.
It also highly depends on how (often) you want to read and write your data. Mainly about how you query the data. Finding a good [partition key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data) might also influence your decision.

Answer (score -1):

It is really a matter of design and preference, not sure it's a coding answer that belongs to StackOverflow's [On-Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidelines.

That article suggests a way to organize posts and comments, since conceptually both are very similar, they could be the same "thing". But you could separate them in different document types and store them in different collections, it really depends on how you want to query the information and how to expose that querying capabilities to other services in your architecture. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45472948/5641598) is a very good architectural answer by one of our PMs.

Regarding pros and cons:

If you store both object types in the **same collection**, you just need to maintain one `DocumentClient` and you can use the same to query comments and posts, they would share the configuration that Collection has regarding indexing, partitioning and provisioned RUs. It is probably the most cost-effective option.

If you store them **separately**, you'd need to maintain multiple `DocumentClient` but you could provision different RUs to each (in case for some reason you wanted to give more RUs to post than to comments) and if you wanted, maintain different partitioning strategies.