# Querying the Cosmos db collection of array data

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am new to cosmos i have a collection i am trying to query the sample is below.
as the data is nested due to the nature of it. we must be able to query the sub sections of the documents also.

I am getting stuck in trying to retrieve the data of the itemCode in the below collection.

Any info would be a great help. thanks in advance.

SELECT * FROM c
where c.customerSites.pricingGroup.itemCode ="2400953"

This query returns no results.

[Data collection sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB8hU.png)

```
{
     "customerSites": [
    {
        "customerCode": "196729",
        "businessUnitName": "XXXXX SOUTHERN LTD",
        "siteCode": "96271",
        "addressCode": "_MAINXXXX",
        "pricingGroup": [
            {
                "itemCode": 2400953,
                "branches": [
                    8999,
                    3001,
                    3002,
                    3003,
                    3004
                ],
                "rates": [
                    {
                        "branchCodes": [
                            8999,
                            3001,
                            3002,
                            3003
                        ],
                        "discountPercentage": null,
                        "derivedRateId": 77735584,
                        "derivedRateClassification": "customrate",
                        "branchLevel": 109,
                        "derivedRateType": "P",
                        "durationRates": [
                            {
                                "durationType": 1,
                                "rate": 125
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
],
"id": "196729",
"dataType": "AccountCustomer",
"_ts": 1547161022
```

}

Comment: There's no question here. Did you try something?

Comment: Please do not include any links to you sample data. A lot of people here will not click on links. Instead provide you samples as `formatted text`

Comment: Yes Nick as i was formatting the data. so that my problem can be visible.

Comment: @Vready - it's unclear what your query is. Please edit your question to show your actual query, and where you're getting stuck.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I am trying to get the values in the collection that can be filtered on the itemCode.

Comment: You cannot query arrays the way you're trying. You'll need to self-join to elements in the array. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27390644/272109) shows how.

Comment: @DavidMakogon that link worked. Thanks David.

Comment: @Vready - great - I'll vote to close this question as a duplicate then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WHERE clause on an array in Azure DocumentDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27390189/where-clause-on-an-array-in-azure-documentdb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do:

```
SELECT * FROM c where c.customerSites[0].pricingGroup[0].itemCode = 2400953
```

[image]